# Does $L_\alpha\prec L_{\kappa^+}$?

Tags: set-theory, cardinals, model-theory

Let $\langle L_\alpha\mid\alpha\in On\rangle$ be the constructible hierarchy. Suppose $\alpha=(\kappa^+)^L<\kappa^+$. Is it the case that $L_\alpha\prec L_{\kappa^+}$?

Comment: No, it isn't. For instance, $L_\alpha$ knows that every set has size $\kappa$, while this fails in $L_{\kappa^+}$ (with $\alpha$ itself being a counterexample).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Andres points out, with $\kappa$ as a parameter we can distinguish between $L_{\alpha}$ and $L_{\kappa^+}$. Even more is true: we can consistently have $L_\alpha\not\equiv L_{\kappa^+}$.

One way for this to happen is for $\kappa^+$ to be a limit cardinal in $L$ (so that $L_\alpha$ satisfies "there is a largest cardinal" but $L_{\kappa^+}$ doesn't). This can be forced, for example, by (over $L$) collapsing everything below an inaccessible. *(Phrased more directly: if there is a successor cardinal $\kappa^+$ which is inaccessible in $L$, then 
we have $L_{\kappa^{+L}}\not\equiv L_{\kappa^+}$.)*

Comment: Assuming $0^{\#}$ exists, we have that $L \models \kappa^{+V}$ is inaccessible (and hence a limit cardinal). That's another way to see this can in fact happen.

Comment: As a sort of converse to the previous comment, if there is no infinite $L $-cardinal $\kappa $ such that $L_{(\kappa^+)^L}\equiv L_{\kappa^+} $, then $L $ does not compute correctly the successor of any singular cardinal, so $0^\sharp $ exists.